# Converting Object or Object<T> to Object<T, T>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, type-conversion

I have been following Imar Spaanjaars' blog about [ASP.NET N-Layered Applications](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/577/aspnet-n-layered-applications-implementing-a-repository-using-ef-code-first-part-5) as well as looking through [ASP.NET Identity](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)'s code practices.

I've run into a bit of trouble with inheritance and calling the base methods.

### Info

First let me show you the base code. Based on Imar I have a `CollectionBase` class which all my list type properties will inherit from.

```
public abstract class CollectionBase<T> : Collection<T>, IList<T> {
    protected CollectionBase() : base(new List<T>()) {}
    protected CollectionBase(IList<T> initialList) : base(initialList) {}
    protected CollectionBase(CollectionBase<T> initialList) : base(initialList) {}
    public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer) {
        var list = (List<T>) Items;
        if (list != null) {
            list.Sort(comparer);
        }
    }
    public void Sort() {
        var list = (List<T>) Items;
        if (list != null) {
            list.Sort();
        }
    }
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
        if (collection == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("collection", "Parameter collection is null.");
        }

        foreach (var item in collection) {
            Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I then have another class which I want to make as generic as possible, using `ASP.NET Identity`'s code practices.

```
// this class is instantiated with 2 types, one for the Id property for emails and one for the Id property for owner
public class Emails<TKey, TOwner> : CollectionBase<Email<TKey, TOwner>> {
    public Emails() {}
    public Emails(IList<Email<TKey, TOwner>> initialList) : base(initialList) {}
    public Emails(CollectionBase<Email<TKey, TOwner>> initialList) : base(initialList) {}
}
```

I am now trying to create a class that inherits from the generic one as a shortcut, similar to how `ASP.NET Identity` does, which inherits from the generic one, with assumed types.

```
public class Emails : Emails<String, String> {
    public Emails() {}
    public Emails(IList<Email> initialList) : base(initialList) {
        // getting error on the 'base' call since there is no signature similar to Emails(IList<Email> initialList)
        // how can I convert the parameter IList<Email> initialList to an IList<Email<String, String>>
    }
    public Emails(CollectionBase<Email> initialList) : base(initialList) {
        // getting error on the 'base' call since there is no signature similar to Emails(CollectionBase<Email> initialList)
        // how can I convert the parameter CollectionBase<Email> initialList to a CollectionBase<Email<String, String>>
    }
}
```

Just in case, here is the `Email` class

```
public class Email : Email<String> {
    public Email(String address, String ownerId)
        : base(address, ownerId) {}
}

public class Email<TKey> : Email<TKey, String> {
    public Email(String address, String ownerId)
        : base(address, ownerId) {}
}

public class Email<TKey, TOwner> : DomainEntity<TKey>, IHasOwner {
    public Email(String address, TOwner ownerId)
        : this() {
        Address = address;
        OwnerId = ownerId;
    }
    protected Email() {}
    public String Address { get; set; }
    public TOwner OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}
```

### Problem

As I have noted in the comments, the problem I am having is that the base class does not have a signature method for `Emails(IList<Email> initialList)` and `Emails(CollectionBase<Email> initialList)`, and of course they shouldn't have. I do know that I shouldn't be calling `base` like am above, but I left it there in case there's a really simple code to make the conversion where that can be called, instead of having to write extra code within the method.

### Question

How can I "convert" the parameter types `IList<Email> initialList` and `CollectionBase<Email> initialList` to `List<Email<String, String>>` and `CollectionBase<Email<String, String>>` respectively?

### Potential Answer

I may have created the answer myself, but I'm not familiar enough to know that this is the way to do it. If this is not, please provide any changes I should make and/or provide a completely different answer.

Here is my class after playing around a bit.

```
public class Emails : Emails<String, String> {
    public Emails() {}
    public Emails(IList<Email> initialList) : base((IList<Email<String, String>>)initialList.Select(email => new Email<String, String>(email.Address, email.OwnerId))) {}
    public Emails(CollectionBase<Email> initialList) : base((CollectionBase<Email<String, String>>)initialList.Select(email => new Email<String, String>(email.Address, email.OwnerId))) {}
}
```

Comment: Where is the type `Email` declared in your code?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I added it.

Comment: Would I have to iterate through each object in the `initialList` and create a new object of the type I want with the proper values?

Comment: Can't you just dump the `Emails<TKey, TOwner>` class?

Comment: This is a generic class so that if someone wants to use it the `Emails` collection, they aren't bound by my type for `TKey` and `TOwner`. The `TKey` and `TOwner` are the types for the `Id` for the `Email` and `User` classes respectively. As stated, I want to use practices by `ASP.NET Identity` which use this. (see https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/RoleManager.cs)

Comment: The code you linked uses a single class hierarchy. You are using two (`CollectionBase<>` and `Email<>`), which is breaking your neck. In your case, `Email` is just a shortcut. If someone wants to use other parameters, they'll have to use the base class or write their own short cut. Your potential solution trades runtime performance for what you consider good architecture. Besides that I am not convinced of the architecture, trading performance is not acceptable in my opinion. At least in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with this, so can you explain what performance issues arise from this so I can learn? Besides that, is my shortcut correctly done, say if I wanted to use my own generic class but use a shortcut like this? If not, how can I improve the architecture? I'm not saying what I'm doing is good architecture. I'm new to this and just learning from reading blogs/code and creating mini projects like Imar's but changing it bit to other things I may learn on the way so that I have a better understanding of what I can/cannot and should/should not do. Thank you so much!

Comment: The call to `Select` is what's making your potential solution slightly slower, because it constructs a new enumerator for an already existing list. The shortcuts look ok. But as mentioned, I would derive `Email` directly from `CollectionBase<Email<String, String>>` and dump `Email<TKey, TOwner>`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I would drop `Email<TKey, TOwner>` too, but the idea behind this, and so I can learn how to do things like this, is to keep the generic class, just as `CollectionBase` is a generic. Is there a `faster` way to do it versus the `Select`? I created a `foreach` loop (which I had to create a new list too) and ReSharper converted it to Linq for me.

Comment: I wouldn't involve any run-time action here. Not if everything can be resolved at compile-time.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, so besides inheriting `Email` from `CollectionBase<Email<String, String>>` there's no compile time way of doing it?

Comment: @NicoSchertler, what do you think about this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34698383/286618. Thanks!

Comment: Not convinced of it either. It also creates new objects when you actually want to use the existing ones.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, thanks. I figured this as well. However, currently the best answer since I still need a way of doing this. Let me know if you got any other ideas, as I value them highly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, this is the solution I am using, until someone can make [Gibran Silvia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698383/286618)'s answer more generic for both function.

```
public class Emails : Emails<String, String> {
    public Emails() {}
    public Emails(IList<Email> initialList) : base((IList<Email<String, String>>) initialList.Select(email => new Email<String, String>(email.Address, email.OwnerId))) {}
    public Emails(CollectionBase<Email> initialList) : base((CollectionBase<Email<String, String>>) initialList.Select(email => new Email<String, String>(email.Address, email.OwnerId))) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can you do a extension method to implement a cast.
Is not possible to do implicit cast because the compiler dosen't know how to convert Generics.List to Generics.List.

To solve your problem try it:

I change the methods to call method in base class.

```
public class Emails : Emails<String, String>
{
    public Emails()
    {
    }

    public Emails(IList<Email> initialList) : base(initialList.ToMyList())
    {
        // getting error on the 'base' call since there is no signature similar to Emails(IList<Email> initialList)
        // how can I convert the parameter IList<Email> initialList to an IList<Email<String, String>>
    }

    public Emails(CollectionBase<Email> initialList) : base(initialList.ToMyCollection())
    {
        // getting error on the 'base' call since there is no signature similar to Emails(CollectionBase<Email> initialList)
        // how can I convert the parameter CollectionBase<Email> initialList to a CollectionBase<Email<String, String>>
    }
}
```

And I do it in a extension method to convert your class:

```
public static class ExtensionListEmail
{
    public static IList<Email<string, string>> ToMyList(this IList<Email> list)
    {
        return new List<Email<string, string>>(list);
    }

    public static CollectionBase<Email<string, string>> ToMyCollection(this CollectionBase<Email> collection)
    {
        return new Emails(collection);
    }
}
```

I hope that I've helped.

Comment: Tried it and it does seem to work. Is this considered `slow` as mentioned by @NicoSchertler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697266/converting-object-or-objectt-to-objectt-t?noredirect=1#comment57142057_34697266?

Comment: This looks like a great solution. Can you make it generic? I don't want to have to create a new extension for every class that follows this architecture. i.e.: What if the type is `Email<Int32, Int46>` or even `Address<String, Int32>`

Comment: so I was able to get the `IList` one as generic, but how can I do the `Collection` one? `public static IList<T> ToList<T>(this IList<T> list) {
   return new List<T>(list);
  }`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no need to create the `Emails` shortcut. Implementing the `Emails` shortcut is something like following:

```
public class StringList : List<string>
{
}
```

which means that in order to use a List object, we create a dedicated class for it. But actually we don't do this most of the time. What we do is like following:

```
var stringList = new List<string>();
```

So if you obsolete `Emails` shortcut, you won't have your problem. Besides, you could use all your other classes as follow:

```
var emails = new Emails<string, string>();
emails.Add(new Email("key", "ownerId"));
```

But of course, the precondition for this is that the `Emails` class is just a shortcut. If you need to implement some specific functions in that class which correspond to the generic types it uses, that is another story.